# How can I use https in my Frontend Project in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I do all the stuff which I found on stackoverflow.. but it doesn´t work for me..

I will show you an example ..

I do this in my package.json in Frontend :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

And that would be my userAction Login but it doesn´t work:

```
export const login = (userID, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });

    const url = "https://localhost/authenticate/";
    const response = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      },
      {
        auth: {
          username: userID,
          password,
        },
      }
    );

    const config = {
      auth: {
        username: userID,
        password,
      },
    };
```

In my backend it would be this way and it works :

```
###
POST https://localhost:443/authenticate/
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
```

the error:

```
POST https://localhost/authenticate/ net::ERR_CERT_INVALID
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? I see there is a difference between the backend and frontend endpoint, try to use this on the frontend: `const url = "https://localhost:443/authenticate/";`

Comment: @Georgy I used it it doesn´t work too .. if I want to login it gives me the Network error

Comment: which error? could you please put the error in your question

Comment: @Georgy you can see it now

Comment: ah, but you don't have a certificate on localhost, right? Not sure you want to use SSL on localhost, usually it should work only on production, in that case you could just check if it is localhost you use just regular `http` if it's production - `https`, but you must have the certificate on your production domain then

Comment: I have my certificates but I don´t know .. why it´s not working @Georgy